# discord.py getting all text channels under a certain category

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to get all text channels under a category as a list but I can only do

```
for guild in client.guilds: 
    print(guild.text_channels)
```

I want to specify it with a certain caregory. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `CategoryChannel.channels`.  Below, I use a converter to get the `CategoryChannel` from the command, but you could also use `guild.categories`

```
from discord import CategoryChannel

@bot.command()
async def comm(ctx, *, category: CategoryChannel):
    channels = category.channels
    print(channels)
```