# Discord - display channel names from a specific category with python

Tags: python, discord

It's possible to display all text channels from a specific category on discord with python if someone send a message to bot for ex.: if xyz send `!vip` message to the bot then he is reply with **all text channels name** from "VIP" category? I can't find threads like this just count of how many text channels are in specific category etc...

I did setup the basic bot (*found on stackoverflow too*) with reply if you send `!hello` to the bot and it's working but can't figure out how to do that which I mentioned above.

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'yourtoken'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!hello'):
        msg = 'Hey, {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await message.channel.send(msg)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: I would use this in a command. There is also an existing post about it on StackOverflow.

Comment: What post? getting all channel NAMES from a category? Can you give me a link about that post?

Comment: This should answer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685771/discord-py-getting-all-text-channels-under-a-certain-category

Comment: Thank you, yes maybe that's what I want but can you explain a little bit more how can I use that please? I think I need to replace `*` to the category name which I want to fetch(?) and how can I call that function if I write `!vip` for ex.: in `get-vip-channels` channel?

Comment: Ah, okay I figured out that I need to type `!comm categoryname` but it's display like this: `[<TextChannel id=833691055723118602 name='test' position=1 nsfw=False news=False category_id=833691033166151740>,` can I get just the channel name wich is `test` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you have to use a command for that. For that you can use `CategoryChannel.channels` and or `guild.categories`.

This gives out a information about the whole category which would look like this:
`[<TextChannel id=ChannelID name='Allgemein' position=0 nsfw=False news=False category_id=CategoryID>]`

***To just display the name, use the following:***

```py
text_channel_list = [] # "Create" a list

@client.command()
async def comm(ctx, *, category: CategoryChannel):
    for channel in category.text_channels: # Get text channel
        text_channel_list.append(channel.name) # Append them to the list
    await ctx.send(f"\n".join(text_channel_list)) # Send the channels in one message
```

*We have to put the `await` statement outside the `for` loop function in order to just receive one message.*

For more information please read the **[docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=category%20channels#discord.CategoryChannel.text_channels)**.

Comment: Thank you it's almost working but duplicates every channel in a new message... (channel names are 0-22 just for dev) you can see [here](https://i.imgur.com/Eh5uMBU.png) that's no problem if the bot sending new messages with each channel name because then I can "bypass" 2000 chars limit but would be great if don't duplicate them.

Comment: Have you already tried to solve the problem yourself? After all, this is not a *"Please code/implement this for me"* platform.

Comment: I know. But you technically gave me a code what is duplicates every channel names. And now I'm struggling with that problem I didn't get any further. I tried everything from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-duplicates-from-list/) ex.: `new_list = [i for n, i in enumerate(text_channel_list) if i not in text_channel_list[:n]] await ctx.send(f"{new_list}") `   but did the same, just duplicates every channels.

Comment: I edited my answer. If you do not know how to "break" a `for`-loop you should indeed read some contributions on this page, because there was a contribution for that as well here: [How to send a list in one message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65225934/how-can-i-send-this-list-as-one-message-in-discord-py) And just because I gave a possible answer that doesn't mean one can't ask for your own contribution. My research shows me that your research was little to nonexistent, otherwise you would have found my posts as well....

Comment: Okay, you are right. I could have been a little more attentive as well, but thank you!